# How to override a specific group policy setting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, group-policy

I am working on testing Cached Exchange Mode for my organization and am having some trouble getting the GPOs to apply how I'd like them to.

We currently have a company wide MS Office GPO. As part of this GPO, Cached Exchange Mode is disabled. I had a GPO created and linked to my section's OU, which I was going to use to test this feature.

I am able to enable caching through that GPO and all is good. However, feedback has been received from some of the users that they would like to have the option to turn caching on or off per workstation. What I was hoping to do was to "unlock" the caching mode options in Outlook (as though the GPO were set to Not Configured) to allow the user to choose whether or not to use it.

So I suppose I need a question... is it possible to configure that GPO the way I'd like? The only way I can see it working right now is if we make a copy of the Office GPO, change the necessary settings, and have it only apply to my users. They would also need to be excluded from the current Office GPO somehow.

Is there any other way I could implement this?

Comment: Are you asking if you can configure the policy to Not Configured?

Comment: Yes and no... I know that Not Configured more or less means that the GPO will have no effect on that setting. I guess what I am *hoping* I can do is explicitly set my GPO to Not Configured (or do something equivalent), so that it will override the parent GPO setting where it is disabled.

Comment: ", so that it will override the parent GPO setting where it is disabled" - That setting does not exist.  You can either allow the user set it themselves, or set it for them, but you can't let the user override it and set it.  What you have have to enable to allow the user to set it, I don't know specifically, this comment is just to save you time waiting for the impossible.

Comment: That is what I thought, I just wanted to double check as this is one of my first forays into the GPO world. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

"Not configured" will not override the default policy. You need to apply a separate GPO (that disables cached mode) for required users only.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete.